# How to convert each excel cell into a csv file

Tags: excel, bash, loops, csv

I have a spreadsheet in excel. There are two columns in the 'Tag-CSV' tab: 'NEW_NOME_TAG' and 'CSV' . I have to transform each cell of column 'CSV' into a CSV file with exact name defined in column 'NEW_NOME_TAG'

IFS=','
while read f1 f2 f3 f4; do
echo "fields[$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4]"
done < a.csv

Comment: The real issue is the [tag:Excel]-based macro required to extract the data from your Excel-file.  Either that, or an [tag:OpenOffice] or [tag:LibreOffice] API script for the data extraction of the two columns as a CSV, with the CSV in the "CSV" column not using the same separator as that used to delimit the 2 columns.  I suggest you use the vertical bar to separate the columns during export to shared CSV file.  That can then be "exploded" into the many files you require.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, export your entire "Tag-CSV" tab as a single CSV file.  For this, it is strongly recommended that you use the vertical bar to separate the columns during that export.

**Then**, once you have the exported CSV that tab, you can then apply the logic of the following script to "**explode**" that CSV into the required multiple *.csv files.

**Demo script**:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="test_sample.csv"

cat >"${input}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
NEW_NOME_TAG|CSV
dummy1.csv|cat,dog,bird,fish,snake,elephant,ant,crab,whale
dummy2.csv|dodge,chrysler,ford,lincoln,buick,cadillac
dummy3.csv|trains,planes,automobiles,ships,rockets
EnDoFiNpUt

IFS="|"
while read filename data
do
    case ${filename} in
        *.csv)  echo "${data}" >"${filename}" ;;
        * ) echo "Ignoring header line ..." ;;
    esac
done <"${input}"

for file in dummy*.csv
do
    echo "FILE: ${file}"
    cat "${file}"
    echo ""
done

The **session output** looks like this:

    Ignoring header line ...
    FILE: dummy1.csv
    cat,dog,bird,fish,snake,elephant,ant,crab,whale
    
    FILE: dummy2.csv
    dodge,chrysler,ford,lincoln,buick,cadillac
    
    FILE: dummy3.csv
    trains,planes,automobiles,ships,rockets
```